# Using math functions in Sql with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-jet-ace

I designed a query in SQL View using MS Access:

```
select floor(num1) from t1;
```

When I run it, I get "undefined function floor".

I get similar errors for `Ceil`, `Mod`,`Power`, `Sign`, `Sqrt`, `Trunc`, and `initcap` functions.

Does the Access database engine's SQL syntax have equivalent functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace Floor() with Int(). I learned this by searching in the Access help files, in this case, hitting F1 while in the query designer, and searching for "functions." That took me to a help topic comparing VBA and T-SQL functions.

You should probably have a look at the [Access database engine SQL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj583214.aspx). I can't find a good online reference for functions that are supported through the Jet/ACE and Access expression services. For some unknown reason, the Access Help has not included Jet/ACE expressions since Jet 3.0 and this aged resource was finally removed from MSDN a year or two ago :(

Keep in mind that the Jet/ACE expression service for use outside Access supports a much smaller subset of functions that is possible using the Access Expression Service when running your SQL inside Access 2007. Broadly speaking, the VBA5 functions (as distinct from methods) that involve simple data types (as distinct from, say, arrays or objects) are supported outside of the Access user interface; for an approximate list of function names see the 'Use Sandbox mode operations with Jet 4.0 Service Pack 3 and later' section of [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294698).

Also, the functions reference in the VBE help should be a starting place.

The help files are not perfect, but a little searching ought to get you what you need.

Comment: Another option is to create your queries as passthoughs.  Then you can still use your sql functions.  Also if you have several joins on large tables or can significantly reduce the dataset on the sql end, passthroughs can increase your performance substantially.

Comment: I see no indication in the the original post that there's a server back end involved. For the multi-joins, I tend to create views on the server to do them and then link to the view, rather than trying to maintain passthrough queries. In general, I wouldn't bother to do even that unless I found that Jet was messing up in the first place. Jet is a lot more efficient than many people give it credit for, it seems to me.

Comment: The SQL reference has moved to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841692%28v=office.14%29.aspx) [2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj583214.aspx);

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function Floor(ByVal x As Double) As Double
'Be Because VBA does not have a Floor function.
'Works for positive numbers
'Turns 3.9 -> 3
'Note: Round(3.9) = 4

    Dim s As String, dPos As Integer
    s = CStr(x)
    dPos = InStr(s, ".")
    Floor = CLng(Left(s, dPos - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: `Floor(CDbl(2))` triggers error #5, "*Invalid procedure call or argument*"

Comment: CDbl(2) you get an integer back 2 and not a double 2.0 in Access

Comment: `TypeName(CDbl(2))` returns "Double", not "Integer".  Don't be confused if it's displayed somewhere without any decimal places; it's still a Double.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Floor isn't available in access, you should use int() as an alternative.  If you insist on using Floor, you could always create a vba module function in your mdb file similar to below but that is probably overkill.

```
Public Function floor(dblIn As Double, dec As Integer) As Double
  decPosition = InStr(Str(dblIn), ".")
  x = Left(dblIn, decPosition + dec - 1)
  floor = x
End Function
```

Similar to the other math operations you described above you may create additional functions to create this set of functionality.