# a query for change of stock data timeframe

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am searching for a simple query that can change stock data for a  lower time frame to a higher time frame. consider the table below

```
                          Open    High    Low    Close   Volume
    Date                                                       
    1999-01-04 10:22:00  1.1801  1.1819  1.1801  1.1817       4
    1999-01-04 10:23:00  1.1817  1.1818  1.1804  1.1814      18
    1999-01-04 10:24:00  1.1817  1.1817  1.1802  1.1806      12
    1999-01-04 10:25:00  1.1807  1.1815  1.1795  1.1808      26
    1999-01-04 10:26:00  1.1803  1.1806  1.1790  1.1806       4
    1999-01-04 10:27:00  1.1801  1.1801  1.1779  1.1786      23
    1999-01-04 10:28:00  1.1795  1.1801  1.1776  1.1788      28
    1999-01-04 10:29:00  1.1793  1.1795  1.1782  1.1789      10
    1999-01-04 10:31:00  1.1780  1.1792  1.1776  1.1792      12
    1999-01-04 10:32:00  1.1788  1.1792  1.1788  1.1791       4
```

it is updated every 1 min. how can I change it to say 2 min data by a query?

Comment: With `update frequency` = 2 minutes, what would be your OHLCV? for e.g. 10.22 to 10.23 do you want Open to be 1.1801 and close to be 1.1814? High to be 1.1819, Low = 1.1801? Then volume to be 22?

Comment: to hans up:it is just an example.think it has a row for 10:30:00.                                                                    to boncadigo:yes.exactly

Comment: to boncadigo:yes.exactly.consider it the same as you said for other time frames like 3 min.in case of 3 min,it will become time:10:24  open:1.1801  high:1.1819  low:1.1801 close:1.1806 volume:34

Comment: @user1956274 sometimes there might not be a tick available for each minute given an illiquid stock or a time frame....so can you confirm for sure if you will have date for every minute?

Answer (score 1):

You want to group things:

```
select floor(time/2) as time,
       sum(volume) as volume,
       max(case when time = 2*floor(time/2) then open end) as open,
       max(high) as high,
       max(low) as low),
       max(case when time = 2*floor(time/2)+1 then close end) as close
from t
group by floor(time/2)
```

The formulas for open and close could be made simpler and more general using `row_number()`, but you would need to specify the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply.It is Access

Comment: @GordonLinoff [`floor` is not available in MS Access SQL but MS Excel. However OP could use `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246087/using-math-functions-in-sql-with-ms-access). Or OP writes his own, but this link has already provided that too..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in `SQL Server`. So you may want to change some of the syntaxes to fit. In terms of [partition check this out.](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/07/29/creating-partition-queries.aspx).

Also assuming your equity is extremely liquid and will never miss a minute tick... ;) This query can be improved further though. Give it a try please.

- ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31ae4/33)

Query: [edited to exclude any ohlcv value that comes as null..]

```
select z.dt, a.opens as o, z.h, 
z.l, b.closes as c, z.v
from (
select Dateadd(minute, 1, x.dates) as dt,
max(y.high) as h, min(y.low) as l,
sum(y.volume) as v
from ohlcv x
left join ohlcv y
on y.dates
between x.dates and 
Dateadd(minute, 1, x.dates)
where (DATEPART(MINUTE, x.Dates) % 2) = 0
group by Dateadd(minute, 1, x.dates)) z
left join 
ohlcv a
on a.dates = Dateadd(minute, -1, z.dt)
left join ohlcv b
on b.dates = z.dt
where not (a.opens is null or z.h is null 
or z.l is null or b.closes is null
or z.v is null)
;
```

Results:

```
| DT                             |O       |H       |L       |C       | V  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| January, 04 1999 10:23:00+0000 | 1.1801 | 1.1819 | 1.1801 | 1.1814 | 22 |
| January, 04 1999 10:25:00+0000 | 1.1817 | 1.1817 | 1.1795 | 1.1808 | 38 |
| January, 04 1999 10:27:00+0000 | 1.1803 | 1.1806 | 1.1779 | 1.1786 | 27 |
| January, 04 1999 10:29:00+0000 | 1.1795 | 1.1801 | 1.1776 | 1.1789 | 38 |
| January, 04 1999 10:31:00+0000 | 1.1781 | 1.1793 | 1.1776 | 1.1792 | 17 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.How does it work for other periods like 5 min.moreover I get a little confused about letters you have used in query.I mean z and a and b.what are they?

Comment: @user1956274 I thought you forgot about this.. ;) althouse `a., b., x., z.` are [`table alias`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). So for 2 minutes you add `1 minute` for 5 minutes you add `4 minutes` to the functions where I have used `DateAdd`

Comment: @user1956274 please try this [sqlfiddle demo for 5 minutes intervals](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31ae4/32). However I am keen to know if this has helped you and if this is what you wanted :) please comment.

Comment: thanks a lot.It is so helpful and It helped me to learn a new concept in sql,I mean table alias.God bless you :)

Comment: @user1956274 then vote up ;) if this answer helped you :D Since you are new, you may not know how to do it, please check [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and +1 for your interesting question.